# Css shape needed to adjust dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am working on this project and i am kind of stuck, hope you guys can help me out.

**How it is now:**

[Image on left case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYCSj.jpg)

[image on right case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkxZS.png)

**What i want it to look like:**

[Image on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIazJ.jpg)

[Image on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmAqA.jpg)

Now, heres is the catch:
Since the images are parallax they fit the screen, however the length of the paragraph can change from small to large, so these diagonal shapes have to adjust accordingly.

Below is the HTML and CSS I am currently working on:

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix bg lbg1">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 sideBox leftBox">
            <h1>
                Why Us?
            </h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix bg rbg1">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 sideBox rightBox pull-right">
            <h1>
                What we Offer?
            </h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.lbg1{
    background-image: url('../images/left1.jpg');
}
.rbg1{
    background-image: url('../images/right1.jpg');
}
.lbg2{
    background-image: url('../images/left2.jpg');
}
.rbg2{
    background-image: url('../images/right2.jpg');
}
.bg{
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.leftBox{
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 100px;
}
.rightBox{
    padding: 30px 100px 30px 30px;
}
.sideBox{
    background-color: #fff;
}
.sideBox h1{
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.sideBox p{
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.sideBox ul>li{
    line-height: 1.5;
    list-style: circle;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS property `clip-path` for a polygonal clipping.

Example:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

This can be used to create a parallelogram clip path.

You can generate it by yourself [here](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Padding to set the paragraph and images at desired position, Use CSS property **FLOAT**. Applying and clearing float correctly will be your answer. For more refer https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp